# Can I setup a WLAN with just a Access Point and Switch

Tags: switch, wireless, access-point

Is it possible to setup a WLAN with an Access Point and a Switch only? I would like to connect wireless devices wireless to the access point which is connected to the switch. Then, have another computer connected via Ethernet to the switch. I want to setup a camera system, not connected to the internet, so that the wireless cameras can communicate to the desktop I have setup with camera software. I don't think it is possible and I will probably need a router, but I thought I just give it a ask before I buy more hardware. Thanks!

Comment: What equipment are you using, model and make?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You certainly can do it:

```
               + . . . . . . . . + . . . . + . . wifi
               |                 |         |
               AP               cam       cam
               |
===+===========+====SW
   |
  pc
```

You definitely don't need a router, but you will have to work out the addressing of your equipment.  Usually cameras etc are configured to use DHCP, so either you run DHCP server on your PC, the access point, or your configure them with static IP addresses.

Whether you can configure DHCP on the access point depends on the model and manufacturer.  Some switches also can do it; again all depending on the model.  There are many choices for the PC's DHCP, all depending on the operating system.

Unless you run some kind of name service, again potentially on the PC or some access points, you'll need all your addressing to be done with IP addresses, not names.

If you've got more than say 10 cameras you're definitely going to want DHCP.  For a standalone system, there's no need to have any naming, just use addresses.